# node.js STDIN works with process.stdin, not when piped

Tags: node.js

I'm using require("child_process").spawn and calling an executable, which at the beginning is pausing for a password to be input; if I use it like below:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var exe = spawn("NameOfExe.exe", [/*arguments*/], {stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr]});
```

It works perfectly (Yes, I know I can do inherit, shush :p ). I can type inside my console and it'll accept it with no issues.

However, if I do it like this:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var exe = spawn("NameOfExe.exe", [/*arguments*/], {stdio: ["pipe", process.stdout, process.stderr]});
exe.stdin.write("Password\n");
```

then the executable doesn't even receive the stdin; it immediately goes to Execution Failed.

I'm completely at a loss for this. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I think I may be onto something!

So I'm 99.99% certain that the executable is using C# and Console.ReadKey to get the password. However, according to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2), an exception gets thrown whenever the In property is redirected somewhere else.

So this explains it, but is there a way around this using Node, or am I at the mercy of the people who made this executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The ReadKey method reads from the keyboard even if the standard input is redirected to a file with the SetIn method.
```

You figured it out. It uses native bindings to the hardware controller/HAL, and not the shell, to handle stdio.